# iText7 : com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Invalid page structure 1

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to shrink my pdf file using itext7-core:7.1.2, but getting com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Invalid page structure 1.

Below code is working fine for other files, but just for one file its throwing this exception. I opened the file manually and its opening correctly.

Below is my code snippet and its throwing exception at PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.getPage(p) line in below code:

```
public ByteBuffer multipartToFile(MultipartFile multipart, String fileName) throws Exception {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = null;
    File originalFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" +"original_" +fileName);
    multipart.transferTo(originalFile);
    originalFile.deleteOnExit();

try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(originalFile)){
    //Shrink original file and make a pdf out of it
    File shrunkFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" +fileName);
    byteBuffer = shrinkOriginalFilByRequiredRatio(originalFile, shrunkFile, is, byteBuffer);
    //File Cleanup
    if(shrunkFile.exists())
        Files.delete(shrunkFile);

}
//File Cleanup
if(originalFile.exists())
    Files.delete(originalFile);

return byteBuffer;
```

}

```
protected ByteBuffer shrinkOriginalFilByRequiredRatio(File originalFile, File shrunkFile, InputStream is, ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("started to Shrink originalFile={}", originalFile);
    try (PdfWriter pdrWriter = new PdfWriter(shrunkFile.getAbsoluteFile())){
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(is), pdrWriter);
        float percentage = 0.9f;
        for (int p = 1; p <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); p++) {
            PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.getPage(p);
            Rectangle pageSize = pdfPage.getPageSize();
        float offsetX = (pageSize.getWidth() * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
        float offsetY = (pageSize.getHeight() * (1 - percentage)) / 2;

        new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.newContentStreamBefore(), pdfPage.getResources(), pdfDoc)
                .writeLiteral(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "\nq %s 0 0 %s %s %s cm\nq\n",
                        percentage, percentage, offsetX, offsetY));

        new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.newContentStreamAfter(), pdfPage.getResources(), pdfDoc)
                .writeLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
    }
    pdfDoc.close();

    try (InputStream isShrunk = new FileInputStream(shrunkFile)){
        byte[] byteArray = ByteStreams.toByteArray(isShrunk);
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception : file Shrink exception {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    throw e;
}
return byteBuffer;
```

}

And the output exception is:

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Invalid page structure 1.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPagesTree.loadPage(PdfPagesTree.java:386)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPagesTree.loadPage(PdfPagesTree.java:343)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPagesTree.getPage(PdfPagesTree.java:120)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.getPage(PdfDocument.java:416)
```

Comment: If it's *just for one file*, chances are that either that file is broken or that it cong contains something special iText cannot cope with, the former option being more probable. In either case the file in question is needed for analysis.

Comment: Yes the issue was with the file, I recreated the pdf and it worked just fine. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the file, I recreated the pdf and the upload was successful.